# Selecting the longest of two strings using pointers

Tags: c, function, max, c-strings, strlen

I am currently studying for an exam and have come across the following question in a past paper:

**"Write a function that accepts two strings. Count the number of
characters in each, and return a pointer to the long string. You may
extend the provided function to complete the solution:"**

```
main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far, I am pretty sure I am close but it does not print anything to the stdout, I have also had this problem with other questions so if anyone could point me in the right direction it would help me a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("The longest is %s", longest("HELLO", "HELLOO"));
    return 0;
}

int longest(char *string1, char *string2)
{
    char longer;
    if (strlen(string1)>strlen(string2)){
        longer=*string1;
    }
    else {
        longer=*string2;
    }
    return longer;
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` call assumes `longest` returns a `char*` (a pointer to a character which acts as a pointer to a string). You defined the function to return an `int`, and the value you actually return is a `char`. You were right the first time: it should return a `char*`. Also, the function needs to be visible when you call it. The simplest way to do that is to move the definition of `longest` above the definition of `main`. (This will also let the compiler diagnose errors.)

Comment: 1) turn on compiler warnings and read them; 2) `printf` will not show anything on line-buffered terminals until you write a newline character `\n` or call `fflush`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close!

Your `longest()` function intends to return a *string*, but it's actually returning a single character, and this is where the wheels all fall off.

Instead we redefine the `longer` variable from `char` to `char *`, which is a pointer to a string. Now it's going to return the longer of the two strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *longest(char *, char *);

int main(void)
{
    printf("The longest is %s\n", longest("HELLO", "HELLOO"));
    return 0;
}

char * longest(char *string1, char *string2)
{
    char *longer;
    if (strlen(string1) > strlen(string2)){
        longer = string1;
    }
    else {
        longer = string2;
    }
    return longer;
}
```

This version also adds a bit of housekeeping to declare the `longest` function before it's used so the compiler knows the types involved.

Turns out you can simplify the function a bit:

```c
char *longest(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    return strlen(s1) > strlen(s2) ? s1 : s2;
}
```

This version, like yours, decides arbitrarily that if the strings are actually the same length, it gives the win to the first string - it's not clear if this matters to you or not.

**EDIT** @Vlad has pointed out that this solution does not properly deal with `const char *` pointers, and of course he's correct. I intentionally left this out because I was not writing a generally-useful function and believe this beyond what the OP was asking about.

But Vlad's right, so I'm including his version here:

```c
char * longest( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return ( char * )( strlen( s1 ) < strlen( s2 ) ? s2 : s1 );
}
```

This is one of those wiggy areas in C where it's hard to do it really well: the function `longest()` does not actually modify any of the pointed-to strings, so it's able to easily handle these `const` strings, but when it **returns** one of them, it's removed the const-ness from the pointer, and this is really the best you can do: other library functions work this way.

It would be nice if C had function overloading (one version for `const`, one for not), or some special unicorn keyboard that carried the `const`-ness of the parameters to the return value, but - alas - it does not.

This is a more advanced topic than the OP probably cares about, but it's worth noting for the wider audience. Thanks Vlad.

Comment: @ikegami - this is just how you do it with general string parameters when the function itself doesn't care about const or not, but the caller may. Standard library functions `index` and `strstr` all do this: it's a compromise at best.

Answer (score 1):

In the assignment there is written

> ...and return a pointer to the long string.

However your function has return type `int` and within the function there are  assignments that do not make sense

```
char longer;
//…
longer=*string1;
//…
return longer;
```

And the function must be declared before its usage.

The function can look the following way

```
char * longest( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return ( char * )( strlen( s1 ) < strlen( s2 ) ? s2 : s1 );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * longest( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    return ( char * )( strlen( s1 ) < strlen( s2 ) ? s2 : s1 );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char *s1 = "HELLO";
    char *s2 = "HELLOO";

    puts( longest( s1, s2 ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
HELLOO
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `(char*)` cast?

Comment: Why not return `const char *`?

Comment: @KeithThompson In C there is no function overloading. So the same function can be called as for constant pointers and for non-constant pointers. As a result such functions return non-constant pointers. See declarations of standard C string functions. For example char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);

Comment: The cast masks a possible error. `char *s = longest("HELLO", "HELLOO"); *s = 'x'; puts(s);` doesn't require a diagnostic but has undefined behavior (likely a segmentation fault). The fact that `strstr()` has a similar flaw is no reason to repeat it.

Comment: @KeithThompson You are totally wrong. Or write a proposal to the C Standard Committee. I am sure it will be rejected. At least because most C string functions must be duplicated in this case. :) One more C does not have function overloading. So it is a standard approach to the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson My answer is the only correct and the best answer. :)

Comment: What am I wrong about? Is it not the case that the code I presented (a) does not require a diagnostic and (b) has undefined behavior? I'm well aware that C doesn't have overloading. One workaround might have been to provide two functions with different names. (C++ overloads `strstr` for this reason.)

Comment: @KeithThompson To be fair, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743848/selecting-the-longest-of-two-strings-using-pointers#comment105635986_59743911) was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743848/selecting-the-longest-of-two-strings-using-pointers#comment105636006_59743911).  This answer's approach uses a common idiom of the standard library.  Rest is banter.

Comment: @KeithThompson Please write a proposal to the C Standard Committee. Less words, more deeds. All other implementations presented here in other answers are unable to deal with constant pointers. So they are unuseful.

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant that two functions are required: one for constant pointers and other for non-constant pointers. So either for constant pointers the function can not be called or for non-constant pointers. Otherwise you will have to cast a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer yourself. This makes your code less readable.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow don't you actually need *four* versions that reflect all four combinations of const/nonconst for the two parameters?

Comment: @SteveFriedl No, it is enough one version as it is written in my answer and in the C Standard. P,lease learn the C Standard and follow its approaches. Your answer is a bad answer because you may not call your function implementation for constant pointers. and usually pointers to string literals now are declared as constant pointers even in C programs.

Comment: Ok, no need to be snippy. I was referring to a language that does support overloads such as C++; your version is as good as you can do for C and I updated my answer to reflect your approach about 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix several issues with longest function:

```
int longest(char *string1, char *string2)   // 1) why return int ?
{
    char longer;                            // 2) why char? it should be pointer
    if (strlen(string1)>strlen(string2)){
        longer=*string1;                    // 3) this is just one char, rather than a string
    }
    else {
        longer=*string2;
    }
    return longer;
}
```

Here's a sample that fixes these issues:

```
const char* longest(const char *string1, const char *string2)
{
    const char *longer;
    if (strlen(string1)>strlen(string2)){
        longer=string1;
    }
    else {
        longer=string2;
    }
    return longer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char * longest(const char *string1, const char *string2)
{
    const char * longer;
    if (strlen(string1)>strlen(string2)){
        longer=string1;
    }
    else {
        longer=string2;
    }
    return longer;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("The longest is %s", longest("HELLO", "HELLOO"));
    return 0;
}
```

Problems in your code:

1. In C, you have to declare (not necessarily implemented, but the signatures need to be defined already) the function before referring to it in your code. See [this link](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Functions);
2. Your return type is `int` rather than `pointer to string` requested by the assignment. Therefore, both variable `longer` and the return type of function `longest` need to be of type `char *`.

Good to have:

- Using `const` assures the caller of the function that no modifications to the strings would be made.